# Server.MapPath() returning a path that does not exist when used with DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a virtual directory setup in IIS6. This maps to a shared network drive.

I can correctly map the path using

```
string mappedPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);
```

I then create a DirectoryInfo object as I want to find some files in the directory.

```
DirectoryInfo updateDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(mappedPath);
```

But then `updateDirectory.Exists` is false?? I can take the string from the `mappedPath` and copy into Start->Run to get to the path so I know it exists. I am authenticating to the webservice using integrated windows authentication and have permissions to the necessary folders.

Is there something obvious I'm missing in the code? Or is this purely set-up and configuration of IIS etc.?

Comment: Can you also post the exact output or value of mappedPath please? I think, there might be some issue with it.
@Adam, he says, he has verified it using Start->Run.

Comment: @Adam: Yeah I can verify it manually as noted above

Comment: @Kangkan: output is "\\\\someserver\\somepath" which is correct and exists but when I create a DirectoryInfo object it returns False for Exists property.

Comment: Are you making any changes to the directory?  `DirectoryInfo` caches information so `.Exists` might be incorrect at the time you call it.

Comment: @Adam: That's a good point actually, I had read that looking into this - it caches so if you create the directory after calling Exists, you need to create a new instance of DirectoryInfo and check exists again. That wasn't the case here though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this link:

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/471616-server-mappath-virtual-directories

`Server.MapPath` doesn't give expected output when used against virtual directories.

If it is server permissions and you are using Windows Authentication, make sure you have this in your config:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

DirectoryInfo returns false on error conditions: if the folder isn't there; you don't have permissions; or it's a disconnected network folder.

Sounds like permissions of your ASP.NET worker process to me - the impersonation will solve this.

Comment: <identity impersonate="true" /> did the trick nicely, thank you.

Comment: Cool, so I can remember something from doing ASP.NET!  Windows Auth is applied to the current user principal, but you need to promote the Worker Process manually.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check whether your service working process account has access rights to that folder. AFAIK windows authentication does not bring impersonation to the working process so it can be different with your windows acct. 
Alternatively (just to prove account issues) you can run the app pool using your account to see if problem will go away.